# How can i disable menu blinking after selecting a menu item in macOS

Tags: menu-bar

I want to disable the slow menu blinking which occurs after I've selected a menu entry from any menu in macOS. It always takes about half a second or more and is just a waste of time since I know what I am doing.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menu_blinking for more information.

Comment: You said, "It always takes about half a second or more", and unless you have a very old Mac, with not much memory or just lots of processes consuming most of the CPU cycles, I just cannot see it taking a half second or longer. It's so fast on my 4 year old system I'd say it taking less the 1/4 second. There might be something wrong with your system if it taking about half a second or more.

Comment: My question is about "How to disable the blinking" and not about "how long it takes". My measurement of time I said in the question was a reflection of my subjective feeling of how much time it might have been and not an actual measurement. Also: It should not matter if you run this animation on a 10 year old mac or the latest and greatest because I'd bet that the implementation is purely based on actual measurement of time, think: "show_blinking_on_selected_menu(duration = 500ms)"

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is just a core MacOS feature built in - if you go into system preferences and General, you can change the color to graphite if you prefer, make it less irritating. Apple made this choice because "It is a visual clue to help the user understand they have selected this option", and after this it is executed.